# GitX-L: missing object 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Tags: git, gitx

I'm getting the following error in [GitX-L](http://gitx.laullon.com/) when opening a git repository:

```
The document “REPO_NAME” could not be opened.

An error occured while trying to open file://localhost/Volumes/SERVER/www/REPO_NAME/.git/.
fatal: missing object 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

Does anyone know what is causing this issue or how to fix it? I don't get the error while using the command line, so I'm assuming it is a problem with GitX-L.

`git fsck` does tell me about a bunch of dangling entries, could those be to blame?

Comment: Check that HEAD points to something - it may be empty. You appear to have a null sha1, and it says you are trying to open the file `.` which is simply the current directory.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error message when opening a repository in 'GitX' (a GUI tool).

For me, the problem was caused by the file `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, which referenced a remote branch which I had deleted:

```
ref: refs/remotes/origin/develop
```

I fixed it by editing the file to contain the name name of a remote branch which did still exist:

```
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like something is wrong with the origin remote ref... Remove the culprit from Terminal with `git branch -r -d origin/HEAD`, or even `git remote prune origin` and re-open it in GitX.

Comment: Didn't work for me: "error: remote branch 'origin/HEAD' not found." This sounds bad, but I don't understand what it really means. Recloning the remote repo fixed the problem for me.

Comment: `git branch -r -d origin/HEAD` worked for me. @Jonathan Hartley - I'm pretty sure that it isn't a bad thing. It means that you don't have a local representation of the remote branch on `origin` named `HEAD`. At any rate, recloning the remote repo, if that is an option, is always a safe bet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

A simple solution is to clone the faulty repository and start using the clone instead. It worked for me.